Транспонирование в MySQL в таблице с повторяющимися значениями и группировкой
Прошу помощи в решении следующей задачи:

Есть таблица с 2 столбцами - номер респондента и id вопроса/ответа на него.
Примерно так:


подскажите как можно транспонировать в таблицу следующего вида

Что важно - количество респондентов значительное, количество вопросов-ответов также(более 100), количество вопросов по респондентам может отличаться.
Работающую функцию транспонирования я не нашел, пробовал через конкантенацию всех вопросов-ответов в 1 ячейку с последующим разделением

Но столкнулся с тем. что не могу найти/написать функцию разделения по разделителю на динамическое количество столбцов.
Прошу помощи с данной задачей.

Ну тут только хранимой процедурой с динамическим SQL... см. как пример: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66136355/10138734
